# token system using paypal IPN?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

This is a follow up on my last post. I finally managed to sort out the paypal IPN issue that I had. its sending the information and it also logs the information into my database. so no issue there any more.

But now I need to credit the users account with the amount of credit they've paid for after successful payment.

I have a database with a table called members and a column called balance.

How can I update the members balance field after successful payment?

this is the ipn.php file code:

```
<?php
// Database variables
$host = "localhost"; //database location
$user = "XXXXXXX"; //database username
$pass = "XXXXXXX"; //database password
$db_name = "XXXXXXXX"; //database name
$test_email="";
// PayPal settings
$paypal_email = 'XXXXXXX@gmail.com';
$return_url = 'http://www.XXXX/successful.php';
$cancel_url = 'http://www.XXXX/payment-cancelled.htm';
$notify_url = 'http://www.XXXXXX/payments.php';
$item_name = 'Test Item';
$item_amount = 'amount';
// Include Functions
include("functions.php");
//Database Connection
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
// Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
$querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

// Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

//The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
$querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
$querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

//loop for posted values and append to querystring
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
}

// Append paypal return addresses
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

// Append querystring with custom field
//$querystring .= "custom=".USERID;

// Redirect to paypal IPN
header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
exit();
}else{

// Response from Paypal
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
  $req .= "&$key=$value";

}

// assign posted variables to local variables
$data['item_name']   = $_POST['item_name'];
$data['item_number']   = $_POST['item_number'];
$data['payment_status']  = $_POST['payment_status'];
$data['payment_amount']  = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$data['payment_currency'] = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$data['txn_id'] = $_POST['txn_id'];
$data['receiver_email']  = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$data['amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
$data['custom'] = $_POST['custom'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

//  $paypal_url = "www.paypal.com";
$paypal_url = "www.sandbox.paypal.com";
  $fp = fsockopen ($paypal_url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
  // HTTP ERROR
} else {
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
   $res = fgets ($fp, 4096);

   if($payment_status == "Completed" || $payment_status == "Pending"){
        // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
        $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
        $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
        // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
        if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){   
         $orderid = updatePayments($data);
         if($orderid){  
          // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database  
          @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database");
          exit();   
         }else{    
          // Error inserting into DB
          // E-mail admin or alert user
          @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Error inserting into DB");
          exit();
         }
        }else{  
         // Payment made but data has been changed
         // E-mail admin or alert user

         //
         @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Payment made but data has been changed");
         exit();
        }        


   }
   if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

        // Used for debugging
        @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Verified Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");

        // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
        $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
        $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
        // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
        if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){   
         $orderid = updatePayments($data);
         if($orderid){  
          // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database  
          @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database");    
         }else{    
          // Error inserting into DB
          // E-mail admin or alert user
          @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Error inserting into DB");
         }
        }else{  
         // Payment made but data has been changed
         // E-mail admin or alert user

         //
         @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Payment made but data has been changed");
        }        

   }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

        // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!
        // E-mail admin or alert user

        // Used for debugging
        @mail($test_email, "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Invalid Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");
   } 
  } 
fclose ($fp);
}
}
?>
```

And this is the code for function.php

```
<?php
// functions.php
function check_txnid($tnxid){
global $link;
return true;
$valid_txnid = true;
        //get result set
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE txnid = '$tnxid'", $link); 
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $valid_txnid = false;
}
        return $valid_txnid;
}
function check_price($price, $id){
        $valid_price = false;
        //you could use the below to check whether the correct price has been paid for the product

/*
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM `products` WHERE id = '$id'"); 
        if (mysql_numrows($sql) != 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $num = (float)$row['amount'];
   if($num == $price){
        $valid_price = true;
   }
  }
        }
return $valid_price;
*/
return true;
}
function updatePayments($data){
        global $link;
if(is_array($data)){   
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
                                '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                                '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
                                '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
                                '".$data['item_number']."'  ,
                                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'
                                )", $link);
        return mysql_insert_id($link);
        }
}
?>
```

the function.php file works with the ipn.php file in order to send information back and forth to paypal and updates the mysql database.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried to create a new input field for balance in my form. and then I've tried to send the input field data (the amount of crdits the users enter to purchase) to the ipn.php file so it will take it to paypal and simply return it back to me into my mysql database and updates the users balance. but that didn't work. the balance database didn't get updated.

Comment: The ipn.php file is visited by PayPal, and they should include the amount the customer spent as one of the $_POST variables, use MySQL to `UPDATE` their current balance + the transaction amount.

Comment: well thanks but that is the whole thing. i think you just repeated what i said in diffrent terms. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you know what to do, all that's left is writing the code, which is not what SO is for.